# Convex optimization in R with sqlp function

Tags: r, solver, convex, cvx

With the following convex problem:

```
minimize ∥Ax−b∥2
subject to l⪯x⪯u
```

It could be done in matlab with CVX, with SDPT3 solver:

```
cvx_begin
    variable x(n)
    minimize( norm(A*x-b) )
    subject to
        l <= x <= u
cvx_end
```

In this way, R has a `sdpt3r` package as well, but i dont know how could it be done to translate this problem with this package.

An example of use of this R package is:

```
# NOT RUN {
#Solve the MaxCut problem using the built in adjacency matrix B
data(Bmaxcut)
out <- maxcut(Bmaxcut)
blk <- out$blk
At <- out$At
C <- out$C
b <- out$b

out <- sqlp(blk,At,C,b)

#Alternatiee Input Method (Not Run)
#out <- sqlp(sqlp_obj=out)

# }
```

Anyone knows how could be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using

```
min y'y
y = Ax-b
L <= x <= U
```

this is just a QP. E.g. use `quadprog`.